# Uploading images and inserting the image url to mysql with node

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, formidable

I have a node.js application which uploads images and stores them in a folder called `uploads`.

I want to store the image url inside of mysql database and then display all of the images which where uploaded with html.

Im using `formidable` to upload the images.

```
app.get('/upload', function (req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.post('/up', function (req, res){
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

    form.parse(req);

    form.on('fileBegin', function (name, file){
        file.path = __dirname + '/uploads/' + file.name;
    });



 form.on('file', function (name, file) {
        console.log('Uploaded ' + file.name);

        connection.query('SELECT * FROM images', (err, results) => {
            // Throw error if find function fails
            if (err) return (new Error(err));

            // Throw error if there is already a file with that name
            if (results[0]) return (new Error('File with that name already exists, please choose another name'));

            connection.query('INSERT INTO images', (error, results) => {


                // Throw error if save function fails
                if (err) return (new Error(err));

                // Throw error if you cannot verifty the save occured.

                if (results.affectedRows !== 1) return (new Error('There was an unexpected error. Please try again'));
                // Send Log to signal successfull upload
                console.log('Uploaded ' + file.name);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to just save the URL of the image in this function:

```
form.on('file', function (name, file){
     console.log('Uploaded ' + file.name);
});
```

Depending on how you are connecting to your database, the syntax should look similar to this:

```
form.on('file', function (name, file){
    database.find({file: file.path}, (err, result) => {
        // Throw error if find function fails
        if(err) return(new Error(err));

        // Throw error if there is already a file with that name
        if(result) return(new Error('File with that name already exists, please choose another name'));

        database.save({file: file.path}, (err, result) => {
            // Throw error if save function fails
            if(err) return(new Error(err));

            // Throw error if you cannot verifty the save occured.
            if(result.count !== 1) return(new Error('There was an unexpected error. Please try again'));

            // Send Log to signal successfull upload
            console.log('Uploaded ' + file.name);
        });
    });
});
```

**EDIT #1:**

In MySQL that would look similar to this:

```
form.on('file', function (name, file){
    connection.query('SQL SELECT QUERY HERE', (err, results) => {
        // Throw error if find function fails
        if(err) return(new Error(err));

        // Throw error if there is already a file with that name
        if(results[0]) return(new Error('File with that name already exists, please choose another name'));

        connection.query('SQL INSERT QUERY HERE', (error, results) => {
            // Throw error if save function fails
            if(err) return(new Error(err));

            // Throw error if you cannot verifty the save occured.
            if(results.affectedRows !== 1) return(new Error('There was an unexpected error. Please try again'));

            // Send Log to signal successfull upload
            console.log('Uploaded ' + file.name);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: im getting an error (ReferenceError: database is not defined)

Comment: dont you need to do a insert statement to insert the url to the database?

Comment: @IsaacBajada that was just pseudo code to show at a high-level what the process would look like, not actually SQL queries. I have updated my answer to relate a little more to what you are looking for.

Comment: im getting an error (TypeError: Cannot read property 'affectedRows' of undefined) i have update my question. thanks a real lot man